# How to change page of splash screen in ionic cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I added the splashscreen plugin to my project with this command:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

After that I add this line in `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

It worked, but I do not know how to change this page at startup.

Answer (score 1):

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wlttul?p=preview)**

Add zero logic to the `angular.run` method and disable the splash screen. Instead create a controller that will be the first controller called. Show a full screen image in the view and do all your loading inside this controller (data, plugins, etc.).

Refer this [tutorial](http://www.gajotres.net/using-views-events-to-create-javascript-pure-ionic-splash-screen/)

Comment: this command has to remove a page of splashscreen but my question is how to change page of splashscreen with another page

Comment: @RimBejaoui:Splash screen created by using an image.You need to edit image.Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the design of the splash screen or the icon, there is 2 way to do this:

1. You can go to this website:
   https://apetools.webprofusion.com/
   and upload a standard icon and splash screen picture (as they instruct there) and then choose your platforms. the site will generate them for you and you must replace them with the orginals in your project:

> root/resources

2. Yo can replace icon.png (1024*1024) and splash.png (2732*2732) located in:

> root/resources

then run command:

```
ionic cordova build [platform]
```

and cordova will build them for you.
Good Luck!